# Using ORCiD as an identity provider with keycloak (does everyone get the error: Numeric value (2225265999) out of range of int)

Tags: keycloak, orcid

I have keycloak 9.0.0 installed on ubuntu 18, and have set up [ORCiD](https://members.orcid.org/api/tutorial/get-orcid-id) as an identity provider.
When a user tries to log in using ORCiD, they get the message: `We are sorry... Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider`

When I look at the logs, there is an error `Numeric value (2225265999) out of range of int`. It seems like "exp" is being returned as a large integer, but keycloak isn't accepting it**.

The log is below (partly anonymized for security)

```
   
Caused by: org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInputException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (2225265999) out of range of int
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"at_hash":"c_ZGpdmc4SRhqu_HuKraMg","aud":"CLIENT-ID","sub":"0000-0000-0000-0000","auth_time":1594127478,"iss":"https:\/\/orcid.org","exp":2225265999,"given_name":"Name","iat":1594127480,"nonce":"xiYL_3IyrnkbPel78RtPgQ","family_name":"Lastname","jti":"25414b35-39a0-44c2-8333-d69378d878f9"}"; line: 1, column: 151] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.JsonWebToken["exp"])
    at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.readJsonContent(JWSInput.java:104)
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.validateToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:530)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (2225265999) out of range of int
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"at_hash":"c_ZGpdmc4SRhqu_HuKraMg","aud":"CLIENT-ID","sub":"0000-0000-0000-0000","auth_time":1594127478,"iss":"https:\/\/orcid.org","exp":2225265999,"given_name":"Name","iat":1594127480,"nonce":"xiYL_3IyrnkbPel78RtPgQ","family_name":"Lastname","jti":"25414b35-39a0-44c2-8333-d69378d878f9"}"; line: 1, column: 151] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.JsonWebToken["exp"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1711)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4014)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3092)
    at org.keycloak.util.JsonSerialization.readValue(JsonSerialization.java:71)
    at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.readJsonContent(JWSInput.java:102)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Numeric value (2225265999) out of range of int
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"at_hash":"c_ZGpdmc4SRhqu_HuKraMg","aud":"CLIENT-ID","sub":"0000-0000-0000-0000","auth_time":1594127478,"iss":"https:\/\/orcid.org","exp":2225265999,"given_name":"Name","iat":1594127480,"nonce":"xiYL_3IyrnkbPel78RtPgQ","family_name":"Lastname","jti":"25414b35-39a0-44c2-8333-d69378d878f9"}"; line: 1, column: 161]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.convertNumberToInt(ParserBase.java:886)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._parseIntValue(ParserBase.java:801)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getIntValue(ParserBase.java:645)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:472)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:452)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    ... 81 more
```

** I realize this question is similar to [the one asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738195/my-id-provider-returns-a-value-keycloak-doesnt-understand-what-can-i-do), but since ORCiD is a major identity provider, I want to know if anyone else has had success using it with keycloak and how they set it up.

** EDIT (2020-10-06): This issue has been resolved by an update in the ORCiD code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concern is currently being addressed on the [ORCID product roadmap](https://trello.com/c/byfjid09/325-reduce-id-token-lifespan-to-24hs-due-to-security-considerations-3). It is being actively worked on, but there isn't a timeline on when this will happen. You can follow the progress at that link.

There is also a discussion thread about this on the [ORCID API User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/orcid-api-users/keycloak%7Csort:date/orcid-api-users/JxyVQeIZ1I8/qg8i2GtCAwAJ).

This information was given to me by an ORCiD representative.

** EDIT (2020-10-06): This issue has been resolved by an update in the ORCiD code.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes here - this has now been addressed and ORCID can be used as a keycloak identity provider.